# Load image as background image with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to load image as background of the parent element. I've succeeded it but the problem is I have several html sections with individual backgrounds.

Is there a way to do it with less coding or any other way?

my code:

```
  var imgFileData1 = $('.bg-img1').attr('src')
  $('#intro').css({'background-image':'url(' + imgFileData1 + ')'});
  $('#bg-img1').hide();

  var imgFileData2 = $('#bg-img2').attr('src')
  $('#home').css({'background-image':'url(' + imgFileData2 + ')'});
  $('#bg-img2').hide();
```

and my html looks like that:

```
<section id="intro"><img id="bg-img1" src="intro.jpg"></section>
<section id="home"><img id="bg-img2" src="intro.jpg"></section>
```

Comment: what am I missed? Why not just put few css rules with 0 line of JS code?

Answer (score 1):

assign some `class` to your `<section>` and `<img>` tags

which makes it easier to select with jQuery

e.g.

**HTML**

```
<section id="intro" class="load-image">
    <img id="bg-img1" class="background-image" src="intro.jpg">
</section>
<section id="home" class="load-image">
    <img id="bg-img2" class="background-image" src="intro.jpg">
</section>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".load-image").each(function() {
  var self = $(this), img = self.find(".background-image");
  self.css("background-image", "url(" + img.attr("src") + ")");
  img.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want to create a generic function that can be used.  For example, you could "tag" your `img` elements with a class ... for example:

```
<img class='moveToParent' ...>
```

and then search for all such classes:

```
$(".moveToParent")
```

Now you have a list of the images that need to have their images moved to the background of their parents.  From there you can use logic similar to:

```
$(".moveToParent").each(i, element) {
    var imgData = $(this).attr("src");
    // Now apply the image to the parent.
});
```